# Call recording on Android 7 and up

Tags: android, call, call-recording

I am trying to implement call recording in my app but due to restricted permission "CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT" (which can only be granted to system apps) I am not able to record audio of other person.
I found an app on play store [Cube ACR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.catalinagroup.callrecorder&hl=en_IN&gl=US) which can clearly record audio of both sides. If Google has disabled call recording then how it can record calls. Is there any workaround to record call which I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cube call recording app is recording calls for some Android 9 and 10 devices by using accessibility feature. You can use accessibility feature to record calls.